# Verwandtschaft von "-lich", "-ig" etc

Tags: etymology

In meinen etymologischen Quellen (DWDS, Duden) finde ich, dass das Suffix *-lich* mit *gleich* und Englisch *like* verwandt ist.
Zu *-ig* und *-isch* findet man hingegen nichts bzw. die Angabe einer Verwandtschaft mit Griechisch *ikos.*

Ich habe dann auch für Englisch gesucht. *-ly* ist laut Etymonline.com verwandt mit *like*, während *-ish, -ic* und *-y* verwandt mit griechisch *iko* sind.

Und ich denke jetzt die ganze Zeit, die müssen doch alle verwandt sein. Aber eine Beleg finde ich nicht.

- Ist es wirklich Zufall, dass *-ig* und *-lich* nicht mehr miteinander zu tun haben als die Funktion?
- Ist das germanische Wort *lika* irgendwie verwandt mit *ikos?*

Comment: Was ist denn deiner Meinung nach die Funktion von `-ig` und `-lich`?

Comment: Die etymologischen Wörterbücher, auf die du verweist, bestreiten ja indirekt eine Verwandtschaft, bzw. belegen zumindest einen unterschiedlichen Herkunft. Woher sollten wir andere Kentnisse ziehen, woraus eine Verwandtschaft ableitbar wäre?

Comment: @Toscho... ein Adjektiv/Adverb machen

Comment: @jarnbjo ... die Spur von "-lich" ended im Germanischen, die von "-ikos" im Alt-Griechischen. Beide Sprachen haben die gleiche Mutter. Ich hatte nicht das Gefühl, das eine Urverwandtschaft ausgeschlossen ist.

Answer (score 1):

Das ist mehr als eine Frage…

> Ist es wirklich Zufall, dass -ig und -lich nicht mehr miteinander zu
>   tun haben als die Funktion?

Haben Sie denn die gleiche Funktion?
lich
hässlich --> Laut deiner Definition gleich dem Hass
scheusslich --> gleich dem Ab(scheu)

http://www.wortdealer.de/2010/04/15/worter-mit-ig-am-ende/

Wenn ich diese Liste durchgehe. Dann würde ich der Nachsilbe "-ig" die Bedeutung "mit" zuordnen.

> Bärtig = mit Bart, dreckig = mit Dreck (beschmutzt), schmutzig = mit Schmutz, zeitig = mit Zeit (in der Zeit, pünktlich)

Dementsprechend haben sie (-lich und -ig), meiner Ansicht nacht, nicht die gleiche Funktion.

> Blumig = mit Eigenschaften der Blume (blumiges Aroma)
>   Erinnert an eine Blume
>
> Dratig = mit Eigenschaften des Drahtes (drahtige Haare)
>   Erinnert an einen Draht
>
> Salzig = mit dem Aroma des Salzes
>
> freudig = mit Freude
>
> freundlich = mit Freundlichkeit? Eher gleich einem Freund behandelt.

Wer ist freundlich?  --> Die Person.

Was bedeutet freundlich sein? Eine andere Person oder andere Personen zu behandeln als wären diese Freunde. Sie zu behandeln wie einen Freund.

--> Die Person verhält sich also zu vielen oder allen Personen genauso, oder gleich also ob diese Freunde wären. Die Person ist freundlich bzw. verhält sich freundlich, gleich einem Freund, sie hat also nicht plötzlich die Eigenschaft, sondern nur das Verhalten eines Freundes.

Wenn wir sagen wollten, das sich eine Person wie ein Freund verhält, also mit dessen Eigenschaften, dann könnten wir sagen, die Person ist freundig. Witzigerweise hat mein Computer Schwierigkeiten mit dem Wort freundig. Und versuchte es automatisch zurück zum Wort freudig zu korrigieren.

Und freudig ist, was man sein sollte, wenn man einen Freund trifft. Den man dann freundlich, also gleich einem Freund behandelt.

The english friendly however is more ambiguous. Since it means being friendly or being like a friend and not acting like a friend towards others. The result is the same, the source is different.

But when I look at the definition of friendly. It says adjective: kind and pleasant, adverb: in a friendly manner.

Does that mean English speaking people are more genuine than German speaking people when they are friendly towards strangers? I don't know. According to the dictionary not.

The German wiktionary says: http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/freundlich

Bedeutungen:
[1] im Umgang mit einer anderen Person höflich und zuvorkommend
[2] Wetter: sonnig, angenehm warm

And declares the word an adjective. Als Adjektiv oder Eigenschaftswort würde das bedeuten, die Person hat die Eigenschaft sich höflich und zuvorkommend mit anderen Personen umzugehen. ABER: Da es dabei um den Umgang also die Handlung der Interaktion mit anderen Personen geht, was wiederum eine Tätigkeit ist. Also handeln, interagieren. In diesem Sinne ist freundlich ein Adverb, weil es die Art des handelns genauer bestimmt.

Adjektiv = Eigenschaft von einem Subjekt
Adverb = Eigenschaft einer Handlung oder Interaktion ist gleich oder als ob.

D.h. -lich = gleich = adverb und -ig = mit den Eigenschaften von = Adjektiv.

Comment: "Salzig" kann man so und so interpretieren. "Mutig" ebenso. Andersrum kann ich "dreckig" auch als "gleich dem Dreck" ansehen, wenn ich das will. Deine Beispiele sind gut, aber ich denke nicht, dass diese Unterteilung einer Prüfung standhält bzw. es gibt einfach zu viele Ausnahmen. Und für mich haben sie die gleiche FUnktion, genauso wie "-ung" und "-heit" die gleiche Funktion haben. Meine Grundfrage ist eigentlich eher die zweite.

Comment: "Blumig" ist wohl eher "gleich der Blume" und nicht "mit Blume", "drahtig" ist wohl kaum "mit Draht" sondern "gleich dem Draht"... nur um noch ein paar Beispiele von der Liste zu nennen (es gibt bestimmt noch mehr)

Comment: I think you're pushing it now... "freundlich" ... why mit "mit den Eigenschaften eines Freundes". Wo ist der Unterschied zwischen "mit den Eigenschafte von" und "erinnert an"?

Comment: I'm pushing it now because I know I'm right, I just have not explained it properly yet. Ok I'll give it another go let me know if that helps.

Comment: "because I know I'm right". Nicht wirklich. Wörter, die auf "-lich" enden können sehr wohl Adjektive sein und umgekehrt enden auch Adverben mit "-ig". "Freundlich" ist z.B. zugleich ein Adverb _und_ ein Adjektiv.

Answer (score 1):

> Ist es wirklich Zufall, dass -ig und -lich nicht mehr miteinander zu tun haben als die Funktion?

**No, probably not.**

The suffix `-lich` seems to be related with `Körper` as in *Gestalt* of something

> **-lich**
>   [...] MHD *-lich*, AHD *-lih*,  AS *-lik*, auch in AE *-lic* und (noch selten) in GT *-leiks*.
>   Gehört sicher zu dem Wort für *Körper* [...];
>   die Adjektive waren also ursprünglich [Bahuvrihi-Adjektive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahuvrihi):
>   *x-leika- "einer dessen Körper/Gestalt x ist", dann bis zum bloßen Adjektivierungs- und Modifizierungssuffix abgeschliffen.
>
> **Leiche**
>   f. MHD *lich-*, AHD *li(c)h* n./f. u. ä. AS *lik* aus G **lika-* n. "Körper, Fleisch, Leiche", auch in GT *leik* n., ANORD *lik* n., AE *lic* n. [...]
>   Die Weiterbildung *gleich* und das Suffix *-lich* setzen eine Bedeutung Gestalt o. ä. voraus; [...]
>   
>   <sub>MHD - Mittelhochdeutsch,
>   AHD - Althochdeutsch, 
>   AS - Altsächsisch,
>   AE - Altenglisch,
>   GT - Gotisch,
>   G - Germanisch,
>   ANORD - Altnordisch,
>   Source: Kluge, Etymologisches Wörterbuch, 22. Auflage</sub>

`-ig` however, seems to have it's routes somewhere else

> **ig**
>   [...] MHD *-ic*, *-ec*, AHD *-ig* neben seltenem *-ag* [...]. Heute das gebräuchlichste Suffix zur Bildung von Eigenschaftsadjektiven; [...]
>
> **-icht**
>   Adjektivsuffix (wie in *töricht*, [...] *südd.* meist als *-et* [...]). In der Hochsprache ist dafür *-ig* eingetreten. Das *t* ist sekundär angetreten, aber schon MHD *-oht*, *-eht*, *-iht*; AHD *-aht*, *-oht* [...]

Comment: Well, thanks for laying it out in detail but that is only the "-lich" part and I do know where that comes from. What about "-ig"? Does Greek -ikos connect to this ancestry?

Comment: @emanuel I'm not sure what's your point, as it is impossible to exclude any influences which these words/suffixes might have had on each other (see also edit).

Comment: I appreciate your effort but the answer as it is now is basically what I say to set up my question. They seem to have different roots. Also, you say "ig" has its root somewhere else without saying anything about that. I think my question is pretty clear. I want to know if there is any evidence for or against them being related in Indo_european. I do have access to the common etymological sources that you quote so this answer didn't offer a single new fact.

Comment: @emanuel well, I've nothing more I could serve with