# Warum nicht frühlinglich?

Tags: suffix, morphology

> - Sommerlich
> - Herbstlich
> - Winterlich
> - *Frühlinglich?

Zwar verwende ich *frühlinglich* manchmal gern spaßhalber, aber es widerspricht natürlich jedem gesunden Sprachempfinden.  Woran liegt das?

1. Es kann natürlich sein, dass *Frühling* frequent genug ist, um eine lexikalische Ausnahme zu legitimieren; aber meines Wissens nach kommt solches "Blocking" eher bei Trade-Offs zwischen analytischen und synthetischen Formen vor (*Wärme* statt **Warmheit*).
2. Scheinbar erlaubt *-ling* regulär keine Kombination mit *-lich*: vgl. **flüchtlinglich*, **engerlinglich*.  Aber das ist natürlich nur eine Intuition mit sehr kleinem Sample.

Über das Suffix *-(l)ing* hat Kluge nicht mehr zu sagen, als dass es der "Bildung von Zugehörigkeitssubstantiven" dient und von einem "ig. *-ko*-Suffix, das an vollstufige *n*-Stämme antrat" stammt.  Also keine genaueren semantischen Ursprünge wie bei *-lich*, das ja selber [ursprünglich "Körper", "Gestalt" bedeutet](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/11002/1626) (also in etwa *röt-lich* = "von roter Gestalt").

Eventuell könnte es sich natürlich auch um simple Phonotaktik handeln: zu viele *li*-Silben hintereinander.  Aber das kommt mir zu ad-hoc vor.

Irgendwelche genaueren Informationen, warum (ob?) *-linglich* nicht akzeptabel ist?

---

(Für die Zweitsprachler: die Formen auf *-ling* werden scheinbar regelmäßig auf *-s-haft* oder *-(s-)artig* abgeleitet, also *frühlingshaft*, *engerling(s)artig*.)

Comment: Es gibt einige wenige Einträge dazu im [dwds](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=public&q=fr%C3%BChlinglich) - Du bist also nicht der erste mit dem Bedürfnis, *frühlinglich* zu benutzen :) Aber das beantwortet natürlich nicht die Frage, warum sich das nicht durchsetzt.

Comment: Laut DWDS ist das Wort Frühling, welches den Lenz verdrängt hat, die bei weitem Jüngste der Bezeichnungen für eine Jahreszeit. Das lässt vermuten, dass auch die zugehörigen Adjektive nicht zur selben Zeit entstanden sind.

Comment: immerhin gibt's ja "frühlingshaft".

Comment: @tofro - aber dafür gibt es kein(?)/selten "herbsthaft", z.B.

Comment: Andere Worte für den Frühling sind *Frühjahr* und *Lenz*. Und hier gibt es die Adjektive *frühjährlich* und *lenzlich* (letzteres wohl sehr ungebräuchlich).

Comment: Dasselbe Phänomen gibt es übrigens auch bei den Monaten: "dezemberlich" und "novemberlich" werden verwendet, bei anderen Monaten habe ich solche Wortbildungen noch nie gehört.

Comment: "Lenzisch" scheint es auch noch zu geben. Allerhand Kitsch in diesem Zusammenhang auch hier: https://sternenvogelreisen.de/lenz-fruehling-woerter/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deutsche (eigentlich germanische) Wortbildung:

Das Suffix "[-ling](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ling#-ling_(Englisch))" wird in vielen germanischen Sprachen verwendet, um aus einem Adjektiv ein maskulines Substantiv mit der Bedeutung "einer, der ... ist" zu bilden.

- Sonderling (einer, der besonders ist)
- Günstling (einer, der begünstigt ist)
- Frühling (einer, der früh [im Jahr] ist)

Das Suffix "[-lich](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/-lich)" (und "-ig") wird orthogonal (u.a.) dazu verwendet, um aus einem Substantiv ein Adjektiv zu machen, das die Eigenschaft des Substantivs wiedergibt:

- herrlich (wie ein Herr)
- wunderlich (wie ein Wunder)
- nämlich (wie ein Name)

*Frühlinglich* würde deshalb aus einem Adjektiv ("früh") ein Substantiv (Frühling - "einer, der früh ist") machen, nur, um es sofort wieder in ein Adjektiv ("wie einer, der früh ist") zurückzuverwandeln. Das ist natürlich nicht besonders sinnvoll und durch solche Reifen springt die Sprache normalerweise auch nicht - genauso kann man auch "früh" verwenden. Nur haben sich die Bedeutungen über die Jahre spezialisiert, dass man das nicht sofort erkennen würde. (Im [Grimm](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/fr%C3%BChling) finden sich mehrere heute ungebräuchliche Bedeutungen für *Frühling*, die sich nicht auf die Jahreszeit beziehen, z.B. ein "zu früh" nach der Hochzeit geborenes Kind)

Die anderen Jahreszeiten sind im Gegensatz zum Frühling keine aus Adjektiven abgeleiteten, sondern originäre Substantive - deswegen funktioniert "-lich" mit denen. (Wahrscheinlich wehren sich übriggebliebene Reste unsres germanischen Sprachempfindens dagegen?)

Comment: Statt "frühlinglich" wird "frühlingshaft" verwendet. Auch das Kompositionssuffix "[-haft](https://www.dwds.de/wb/-haft)" hat die Funktion, aus einem Substantiv ein Adjektiv zu machen. Nach der Logik Deiner Antwort wäre also "frühlingshaft" ebenfalls nicht sinnvoll. Ist also doch der holprige Klang von "frühlinglich" der eigentliche Stolperstein?

Comment: @PaulFrost "-haft" ist ein wesentlich neueres Kompositionssuffix als "-lich" (stammt aus dem MHD), daher nicht so "symmetrisch" zu "-ling" und deswegen auch nicht so offensichtlich "vor- und zurück". Wahrscheinlich stört es uns deshalb nicht so.

Comment: Könnte zusätzlich die Aussprache eine Rolle spielen? Es dürfte keine [Euphonie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphonie) im engeren Sinne sein (wie "hoffen-t-lich" oder "amerika-n-isch"), aber "frühlingslich" hat meiner Meinung nach Stolperpotential für die Zunge.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Wahrscheinlich schon - ein bißchen. Bei mir wehrt sich allerdings eher der Kopf als die Zunge.... (ich sehe übrigens keinen Grund für ein Fugen-s, das haben ja *sommerlich* und *herbstlich* auch nicht)

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck Ich sehe auch den Wortklang von "linglich"als wesentlichene Teil des Phänomens. Z.B klingt "dínglich" nicht holprig.

Comment: Es gibt auch noch andere Suffixe, die sich nicht kombinieren lassen, etwa -chen und -in. Wir sagen "Frauchen" (und machen sogar eine Ausnahme für die ch-Ausprache) statt *Herrinchen oder *Herrchenin. Bei Hunden muss sich sogar ohne dritte Möglichkeit zwischen "Hündin" und "Hündchen" entscheiden. Auch etwa *richerinlich (zu "richterlich") gibt es nicht.

Comment: Mir gefällt das Argument der "unnötigen Adjektivbildung". Ich denke dabei an die Vorsilben von bestimmten Nutzpflanzen: _Winterweizen_, aber _Frühkartoffeln_.